# Submit form after getting PHP file via AJAX and placing in form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

The programming is being done in Phonegap. I am trying to submit a form with JQuery. I am getting data from two separate PHP files and loading them into different ID's in the form. I am not having an issue getting the data, but the form is not posting. Upon some debugging, it appears to be it is because of the second php file which includes checkboxes.

The HTML code is below:

```
<div id = "result"></div>
    <form method="post" name = "inviteform" id = "inviteform">
    <p>
        <select name="groupstrip" id = "groupstrip" class="formdrop" /><br />

</p>
<input type='hidden' name='user_name1' id='user_name1' value=''>
<p><input type = "button" id="grpsubmit" name= "grpsubmit" class="formsubmit" value = "Invite"></p> 

    <nav id="primary_nav">
<ul>
    <div id = "friendsinv"></div>
</ul>
</nav>

    </form>
```

The Javascript is below:

```
var invgrpurl = "http://www.website.com/app/invgrps.php?userid=" + items;
var invfrndurl = "http://www.website.com/app/invfrnds.php?userid=" + items;  
$.ajax({
url: invgrpurl,
dataType: "text",
type: "GET",
success: function (data){
     //manually insert the page
     $("#groupstrip").html(data);
}
});
$.ajax({
url: invfrndurl,
dataType: "text",
type: "GET",
success: function (data){
     //manually insert the page
     $("#friendsinv").html(data);
}
});
$("#grpsubmit").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$.post( 'http://www.website.com/app/invitemany.php', $("#inviteform").serialize(), function(data){
    $("#result").html(data);
    $('#inviteform')[0].reset();
});
});
```

The main data from the PHP file that is causing the issue is:

```
    <li><div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <?php 
echo '<input type= "hidden" name = "id[]" id = "id[]" value="' . $rowid . '"></input>';
echo '<input type="checkbox" aria-label="..." name = "friends[]" id="friends[]" value="' . $y2aac . '">';
echo '</span>';
echo '<input readonly="readonly" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="' . $fullname . '" placeholder="' . $fullname . '">';
?>
 </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div>
</li>
```

Any help on getting this to submit would be greatly appreciated

Comment: any browser error? Have you tried validating the html that the PHP returns?

Comment: have tried display your data on console what it shows>